# Is it best to declare global variables in a header file or environment file in a C project

Tags: c, security, environment-variables, global, gitignore

I want to know about best practices with C, in creating a API connection wrapper, I have credentials and a variety of non-security related global variables.  This will be in a public git repository so I don't want to expose sensitive data.  However, I need the security data at compile time, not just at runtime.  I see the git ignore file templates on github, but am not sure where to start.  What is the process to organizing globals in a secure way?

The example directory includes:

```
Project
 -data
 -src
  -main.c
  -header.c
  -header.h
 -env
  -credentials.env
 Makefile
```

Comment: C can't get declarations from environment files, you have to use header files. But you can use macros for the values, and the build script can assign these macros from the environment files.

Comment: I would recommend you start to think about if you *really* need global variables to begin with. Often you don't. And when you really do, then not as many as you might think. If you start to get more than a couple of global variables, shared between translation units, then you should take a step back and rethink your design.

Comment: Declare or define? An `extern` declaration could go in a header file, but the variable definition should not.

Comment: It is _best_ to have no global variables at all.  Never necessary, always a poor design choice.